# Regex to match word that does not begin with a dot without using ^ or $

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex to match all words that do not begin with a `.`. This word may be in the middle of a string, etc. and hence it is not guaranteed to be at the start or end of the string.

I have search online for answers to no avail as the other answers require the use of `^` or `$`. The current non-working version I have is as follows:

```
(?!\.)(\w+)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Are there any solutions to this problem?

**Update**

I intended to surround the matching word with `<span>`s and I figured a regex will be what I need, unless the community has better suggestions of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: `/(^|\s+)(?!\.)(\w+)/g`

```js
let string = `test1 .test2 test3 .test4 test5 .test6 test7 .test8`;
console.log(string.match(/(^|\s+)(?!\.)(\w+)/g));
```

But it adds spaces in front of each word that is not in the beginning. Although if what you want is to replace them then I guess that works:

```js
let string = `test1 .test2 test3 .test4 test5 .test6 test7 .test8`;
console.log(string.replace(/(^|\s+)(?!\.)(\w+)/g, `$1<span>$2</span>`));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution with partial regex**

Use `split`, `filter`, `startsWith` and `/\s+/`

```
var str = "This is not .a sentence"
var output = str.split(/\s+/).filter( s => !s.startsWith(".") )
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = "This is not .a sentence";
var output = str.split(/\s+/).filter(s => !s.startsWith("."));
console.log( output );
```

For replacing matched words

```
var str = "This is not .a sentence"
var output = str.split(/\s+/).map( s => !s.startsWith(".") ? "<span>" + s + "</span>" : s ).join( " " );
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = "This is not .a sentence"
var output = str.split(/\s+/).map(s => !s.startsWith(".") ? "<span>" + s + "</span>" : s).join(" ");
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: The reason why I used regex was because I needed to replace the matching words with something else. I think this solution makes it more complicated and difficult?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with? Please update your question with exact details.

Comment: @qwerty I have added a demo.

Comment: Whoa that's an interesting solution :) Though I'll give this one to @revilheart since I technically asked for a regex solution

Comment: No worries, Glad that you found it useful.

Comment: @gurvinder372 you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/0ed6nLq3/ using regex and replace. 